# Rewrite rule in .htaccess and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i would like the url being rewritten automatically from :

```
hello.com/a-b-c/0/
```

to:

```
hello.com/a-b-c/1/
```

I have a rewrite rule on .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+)/0/?$ $1/1/ [NC,L]
```

But that doesn't seem to work. may I know what is the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `that doesn't seem to work`? Is it redirecting to some other URL or not redirecting at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule for redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/0/?$ /$1/1/ [R,L]
```

Or for internal rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)/0/?$ /$1/1/ [L]
```